# Retrieve only the first row with ORDER BY

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that contains salary increase history (Oracle) `emp_id` - for employee identification, `inc_date` - the date that the salary was changed and inc_amount - the amount of the change in salary.  I would like to get the `inc_amount` for the last `inc_date.`

```
 emp_pay_inc:



==============================
emp_id | inc_date | inc_amount
==============================
625    | 1/1/2002 | 0
625    | 5/6/2003 | 12000
625    | 1/7/2004 | 35000
625    | 8/1/2009 | -5000
```

pseudo code for what I would like the query to do:

```
SELECT epi.inc_amt
  FROM emp_pay_inc epi
 WHERE epi.inc_date = MAX(epi.inc_date) -- I know this won't work, it is just for illustration
```

What I have tried (I didn't want to use a sub-query in the event that there would duplicate `inc_date` for the same `emp_id`:

```
SELECT epi.inc_amt
  FROM emp_pay_inc epi
 WHERE ROWNUM = 1 
 ORDER BY epi.inc_date
```

But this doesn't work.  It returns the `inc_amount` 0 for `inc_date` 1/1/2002.  Apparently Oracle stores the `ROWNUM` as they appear in the original table not the data set returned by the query.

Comment: turn your pseudocode into a proper query by creeating the actual SELECT that will return the max date and id, then use that in a JOIN with your table

Comment: @Randy I didn't want to use a sub-query in the event that there would duplicate inc_date for the same emp_id

Comment: Are all the dates different? What if there are several records with the same `inc_date`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able use a subquery for this:

```
SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT epi.inc_amt FROM emp_pay_inc epi ORDER BY epi.inc_date DESC)
WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
```

Comment: I think ur order by should use `desc` since he is looking for max

Comment: @JafarKofahi Thanks, updated the answer to include the sort order.

Comment: This works in the one emp_id example, but not the general case.

Comment: @PatrickMarchand I'm not sure I follow you. What is the _general case_ in which this query doesn't work?

Comment: @Mike - Sorry, I may have misunderstood your requirement that you only want to return a row with the latest inc_date regardless of the emp_id but I was just thinking that you may want to have one row per distinct emp_id.

Answer (score 5):

I guess you want this for each employee.

```
SELECT emp_id, inc_date, inc_amount
  FROM (SELECT emp_id,
               inc_date,
               inc_amount,
               ROW_NUMBER ()
                  OVER (PARTITION BY emp_id ORDER BY inc_date DESC)
                  r
          FROM emp_pay_inc)
 WHERE r = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT epi.inc_amt
 FROM emp_pay_inc epi
 WHERE epi.inc_date = (SELECT MAX(epi.inc_date) from emp_pay_inc)
```

If you want you can add emp_id also if you want for some specific id

Comment: I'm not sure this would work if there's duplicate values for `inc_date`.

Comment: @Mike there should no error since `select MAX(...) ...` always returns one record. It could be even a better solution if we expect all the records having the the highest value of `inc_date`

Comment: The `select MAX(...)` portion does indeed return a single record; however, that record is used in the where clause. There may be multiple rows that have an `inc_date` equal to that of the `MAX(inc_date)`.

Comment: @C.Champagne - max returns one date, but there's nothing indicating you can't have two records with the same `inc_date`. (Could be a yearly pay-rise so everyone has a record the same day, unless the `where` clause specifies an ID). Of course, if there are, which one you get back from the `rownum` check is kind of random if it's only ordered by `inc_date desc`...

Comment: Hi Mike it would return the one value which will be max. Even if there are two.

Comment: @Mike That is what I meant. This select can return several records and it could be interesting to get them all and not just one of them because it might be an information itself or there should be another criteria to determine which one to get. (rownum = 1 in this case is a bit arbitrary. Anyway this is up to Azzi to determine it.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle first select records satisfying the condition (rownum <= 1) and then orders them.

You can try  this:

```
SELECT * FROM 
   (SELECT epi.inc_amt
       FROM emp_pay_inc epi
       ORDER BY epi.inc_date desc)
WHERE ROWNUM = 1
```

...but I am not sure that it is the optimum way in that case.
You can also try

```
SELECT epi.inc_amt FROM emp_pay_inc epi
   WHERE epi.inc_date = 
      (SELECT MAX(epi.inc_date) FROM emp_pay_inc epi)
```

which might be better if several records have the same date and you need all of them

Comment: Oracle will optimise this if `inc_date` is indexed (you'd see `stopkey` in the explain plan, I think). But this is the same as Mike's answer, including the sort ordering problem that originally had.

Comment: @AlexPoole yep I completed my answer too late. I am not sure there  is a better solution and as you mentioned it, using an index should help.

Answer (score 0):

here's an idea:

```
select emp_id, inc_date, inc_amount, rank() over (order by inc_date desc)
from emp_pay_inc 
where rank = 1
```

Comment: Don't forget - rank allows for ties (you can have more than one row with a rank of 1.) I think what you're getting at is what Ramblin' Man posted above. :)